# how to install flutter on raspberry pi zero 2 w?

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I am attempting to install Flutter on my Raspberry Pi by following the official instructions. However, during the installation process, I encounter an issue where the process seems to be stuck while resolving dependencies.

Here are the details of the issue:

Building flutter tool...
Resolving dependencies... (13.6s)
Got dependencies.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you!